How should a clique tree of a graph be constructed?
The following definition is derived from page 132 of the book:  A Guide to Graph Algorithms, T. Kloks and M. Xiao, Singapore: Springer, 2022.
Definition 4.6. A clique tree of a graph $G$ is a pair ( $\mathrm{T}, \mathcal{C}$ ) where $\mathrm{T}$ is a tree and $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all maximal cliques in $G$. Furthermore, there is a bijection $\mathrm{~V}(\mathrm{~T}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ which satisfies the property

for each vertex $x \in V(G)$ the maximal cliques that contain $x$ form a subtree of $\mathrm{T}$ under the bijection.

After reading the definition, I'm still not sure how this $\mathrm{T}$  is derived. I understand that the vertices of T correspond to the maximal cliques of $G$, but I'm not clear on how the edges between the vertices are determined.
Therefore, I also don't  understand the following sentence on page 133 of the book.

Chordal graphs that have a clique – tree which is a path are called
interval graphs.

In the book, another definition of interval graphs is the one we commonly use, which is: A graph is an interval graph if it is the intersection graph of a collection of intervals on a line.
For example, what are clique trees of the following two graphs? They are all chordal graphs. Moreover, is the clique tree of a chordal graph unique?

Note that, (a) is an interval graph (as determined by SageMath), while (b) is not an interval graph (proof can be found at the link).

Have you written down the set of maximal cliques for each of these these graphs? Do that, then read the definition in the examples.

Yes, but I'm still unclear about the edge set of the tree. I suppose the goal is to obtain a tree (I'm also unsure about its uniqueness).

It is not unique, example $(\text{a})$ in your question has two possible trees: a line tree or a star tree

I think there might also exist a graph for which no clique tree is possible. Will post if I find an example

@EnEm In the book, a theorem which shows that a graph has a clique tree if and only if it is a chordal graph.

To understand the construction of T in a clique tree involves mapping maximal cliques of G to the nodes of the T and establishing edges based on shared vertices between these cliques. This ensures that T captures the structural relationships among maximal cliques in G, forming a Tree that represents the decomposition of G into these Cliques.
let me illustrate a example to make it more easy to understand:

graph (G) = Has Vertices V(G)={1,2,3,4,5} and Edges E(G) ={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{3,5}}
Maximal Cliques: C={{1,2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{3,5}}
Clique Tree(T,C):

T will have 4 nodes, one for each maximal clique.
We establish edges in T based on shared vertices between cliques
Node 1:{1,2,3}
Node 2:{2,4}
Node 3:{3,4}
Node 4:{3,5}

Edges in T

Between Node 1 and Node 2(shared vertex{2})
Between Node 1 and Node 3(shared vertex{3})
no direct shared vertices between Node 2 and Node 3
Between Node 3 and Node 4(shared vertex{3})
In this T would be a tree with nodes corresponding to the maximal cliques and edges indicating overlap between these cliques
